# How to make camera always parallel to horizon?

Tags: unity-game-engine, camera

I am trying to create a simple FPS character. I add a camera to character's head and faced with a problem: when I change animation to aim with rifle, character's camera becames not parallel to horizon. How can I reduce that angle?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply this script to the camera

```
public class CameraLeveler : MonoBehaviour
{
    void Update () {
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(transform.parent.forward, Vector3.up);
    }
}
```

This will ensure that camera has the same forward as it's parent (the head), but it's up vector uses world up as opposed the head's up, which it looks like is being tilted by the animation.

Answer (score -1):

Try this in camera script

```
void Update () {
    If (this.transform.rotation.Y > 1) {
this.transform.rotation.Y = 0
}
}
```

It’s check if camera rotate in “Y” > 1

Comment: No. No. Rotation Y is horizontal rotation (looking left/right). Z is the rotation that should stay 0.

Comment: This  `if` would be completely redundant btw. You could simply always set the value to `0`. **But** in Quaternion it's not enough to just set `y` or `z` to `0`! The camera might still be twisted by `w`.